# How to fetch user public Facebook data using Facebook Id?

Tags: facebook, api

I am developing an app which requires data from social networks..I wanted to know how to fetch details of a person from his fid in Facebook.I want to fetch only the data are marked public.From google search i got to know that we can use rest API or java API to get the data but it requires API key or access token which are generated only after logging in to the Facebook. please explain me if there is any other way to fetch the details.

Answer (score 1):

> From google search i got to know that we can use rest API or java API to get the data

Rest API is deprecated, and such a thing as a “Java API” does not exist – it’s just the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) that you’ll mainly use to get information from Facebook, and it’s quite well documented.

> but it requires API key or access token which are generated only after logging in to the Facebook.

Of course you will need an app to be able to talk to the Graph API – but it does not require a user to login/“connect” to your app just to read *basic* (public) profile info. An *app access token* will be enough for that.